# How to "merge" certain records from SQL output and build array?

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I have a SQL statement that outputs the following:

```
EVTYPE          LOGDATE         QUAL    QUAL2   QUAL3   EVSTRING
Viewed          05:29:19.000    -1      4       2       NULL
Comment         05:29:24.083    0       0       NULL    Application was successfully launched
Comment         05:29:24.437    0       0       NULL    Details: xx.xx.xx.xx
Action          05:33:12.000    1       1       982     Acme Anvils
Response Time   05:33:12.000    -1      4       2       NULL
Comment         05:33:50.000    0       0       NULL    Contacted Manager who stated
Comment         05:33:50.000    0       0       4062146 his floor cleamer caused the alarm with a broom. The broom is
Comment         05:33:50.000    0       0       4062146 near the door when the alert was sent.
Comment         05:33:51.890    0       0       NULL    Verified (04m 24s 00ms)
Action          05:33:53.000    12      0       -1      NULL
Resolution      05:33:53.000    -1      1       -1      NULL
```

You can see there are different Event Types (first column - EVTYPE) and it's possible for a comment that is too long for one line to have multiple records. This is indicated when it's a Comment type event and "QUAL3" has a value. New comments start when QUAL3 is NULL and EVTYPE is Comment. The "multi-line" comment entry starts with "Contacted Manager" and ends with the "near the door..." line.

What I am trying to do is concatenate those multi-record comment entries into a single "record" for storage in a PHP array.

I am using PHP and a while loop to iterate through the resultset, but I am having trouble with the conditions to know when it's "clear" to finally add the record to the array.

Here is my code:

```
// Comments Can Span Multiple Records, So May Need to Maintain Through Iterations
    $currComment = '';
    $prevComment = '';
    $strFullComment = '';
    $blnOutputPreviousComment = false; // To Keep Track Of Number Of Comment Entries

    $prevEVTYPE = ''; // For Comparison To Know When "Comment" Entries Are Done 
    $evtype = '';
    $prevQUAL3 = ''; // Will Be Null For Each New Comment Entry
    $prevAlarmDT = '';
    $alarmdt = '';

    $dtOffset = ''; // ReView Entries Are Not Always Correct Offset - First Record (The Alarm) Will Always Have Correct Offset, So Use It

    $blnFirstRecord = true; // Used For Storing DT Offset From First Record Only

    while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) )
    {

        if ( $blnFirstRecord )
        {
            $dtOffset = trim(odbc_result($result,"OFFSET"));
            $blnFirstRecord = false;
        }

        if ( $blnOutputPreviousComment && $prevComment !== '' )
        {
            $data["data"][] = array("alarmdt"=>$prevAlarmDT, "activity"=>"DEBUG 1: ".$prevComment);
        }

        if ( $blnCreateEntry && $prettyString !== '' )
        {
            $data["data"][] = array("alarmdt"=>$alarmdt, "activity"=>"DEBUG 2: ".$prettyString);
        }

        // Boolean To Determine If New Array Entry Is Needed
        $blnCreateEntry = true;

        $prevEVTYPE  = $evtype;
        $prevQUAL3   = $qual3;
        $prevAlarmDT = $alarmdt;

        if ( $prevEVTYPE === 'Comment' )
        {
            $prevComment = $currComment;
        } else {
            $prevComment = '';
        }

        $evtype   = trim(odbc_result($result,"EVTYPE"));
        $alarmdt  = date("m-d-y h:i:s A", strtotime( $dtOffset.' minutes', strtotime(trim(odbc_result($result,"LOGDATE"))) )); // Adds -360 (Whatever The Offset Is) To The LOGDATE
        $location = trim(odbc_result($result,"FULLNAME"));
        $contid   = trim(odbc_result($result,"CONTID"));
        $evname   = trim(odbc_result($result,"EVENTNAME"));
        $stcode   = trim(odbc_result($result,"STCODE"));
        $gsectime = trim(odbc_result($result,"GSECTIME"));
        $qual     = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL"));
        $qual1    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL1"));
        $qual2    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL2"));
        $qual3    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL3"));
        $qual4    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL4"));
        $qual5    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL5"));
        $qual6    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL6"));
        $qual7    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL7"));
        $qual8    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL8"));
        $qual9    = trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL9"));
        $qual10   = ucwords(strtolower(trim(odbc_result($result,"QUAL10")))); // Will Be Area Description When NOT NULL
        $sigqual  = trim(odbc_result($result,"SIGQUAL"));
        $sysdescr = trim(odbc_result($result,"DESCR"));
        $commsno  = trim(odbc_result($result,"COMMSNO"));
        $area     = trim(odbc_result($result,"AREA"));
        $areaname = '';                                  // Use QUAL10 When It Is NOT NULL
        $contact  = trim(odbc_result($result,"CNAME"));
        $pointid  = trim(odbc_result($result,"POINTID"));
        $zonenum  = trim(odbc_result($result,"ZONE"));
        $usrid    = trim(odbc_result($result,"USRID"));
        $evstring = trim(odbc_result($result,"EVSTRING"));
        $fachrs   = trim(odbc_result($result,"FACHRS")); // Resolution Code
        $attributes = '';
        $prettyString = '';

        // First Determine Record Type
        switch ( $evtype )
        {
            case 'Alarm':

                // Convert Integer To Bit Lookup For Alarms
                $arrAttributes = ConvertSigqual($sigqual);
                foreach ( $arrAtributes as $val )
                {
                    $attributes .= ' ' . $val;
                }

                $prettyString = $evname . ' [' . $stcode . '] on ' . $qual10 . ' point ' . $pointid . ' [' . $zonenum .']';
                break;

            case 'Viewed':

                $prettyString = $qual3 . ' Seconds Until Viewed';
                break;

            case 'Comment':

                if ( $qual3 == '' )
                {
                    $currComment = $evstring;
                } else {
                    $currComment .= ' ' . $evstring;
                }

                // New Comment Directly Following A Single New Comment
                if ( $prevEVTYPE === 'Comment' && $prevQUAL3 === '' ) {
                    $blnOutputPreviousComment = true;
                    $blnCreateEntry = false; // Don't Create Entry For Comments - Handled In Comparison Each Iteration
                    break;
                } 

                // Multiple-Line Comment 
                if ( $qual3 != '' ) {
                    $blnOutputPreviousComment = false;
                    $blnCreateEntry = false; // Don't Create Entry For Comments - Handled In Comparison Each Iteration
                    break;
                }

                // New Comment Following Multiple-Line Comment
                if ( $qual3 === '' && $prevQUAL3 != '' )
                {
                    $blnOutputPreviousComment = true;
                    $blnCreateEntry = false; // Don't Create Entry For Comments - Handled In Comparison Each Iteration
                    break;
                }

                if ( $prevEVTYPE !== 'Comment' && $qual3 == '' )
                {
                    $blnOutputPreviousComment = false;
                }

                $blnCreateEntry = false; // Don't Create Entry For Comments - Handled In Comparison Each Iteration
                break;

            case 'Action':

                // Different Types Of 'Action' - Loop Through Them
                if ( $qual == "1" ) // Contact
                {
                    // Different 'Outcomes' Of A Contact - Loop Through Them
                    $contact_result = '';
                    switch ( $qual7 )
                    {
                        case "0":
                            $contact_result = 'Pending Contact With ' . $evstring;
                            break;
                        case "1":
                            $contact_result = 'Contacted ' . $evstring;
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            $contact_result = $contact . ' Was Busy ';
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            $contact_result = $contact . ' Is Not In';
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            $contact_result = 'Error Contacting ' . $evstring;
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            $contact_result = 'Left Message With ' . $evstring;
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            $contact_result = 'No Answer From ' . $evstring;
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            $contact_result = 'Aborted Contact Attempt With ' . $evstring;
                            break;
                        case "8":
                            $contact_result = $contact . ' Will Not Respond';
                            break;
                        case "9":
                            $contact_result = "Reverse Command Issued";
                            break;
                        case "10":
                            $contact_result = $contact . " Notified Via Fax Or Email";
                            break;                              
                    }
                    $prettyString = $contact_result . ' at ' . $pointid;
                } else if ( $qual == "12" ) {
                    $prettyString = 'Alarm Closed';
                }
                break;

            case 'Response Time':

                $prettyString = $qual3 . ' Seconds Response Time';
                $blnCreateEntry = false;
                break;

            case 'Resolution':

                $prettyString = 'Alarm Resolved As ' . $fachrs;
                break;
        }

        // Non-Comment Entry Following A Comment Entry(ies)
        if ( ($prevEVTYPE === 'Comment' && $evtype !== 'Comment') || $prevEVTYPE !== 'Comment' )
        {
            $blnOutputPreviousComment = true;
        }

    }
```

I have gotten close, but the multi-line comment entries output the first and last records. I just want to make sure I'm not leaving out any records, but still able to combine the multi-line comment entries into a single array entry.

Sorry for the length, but wanted to provide all necessary work done thus far.

EDIT: Here is the expected output - Some entries are from fields that I've removed from SQL above for readability purposes, but ARE returned with the SQL results:

PHP After json_encoding:

```
{
"status":"success",
"data":
    [
        {"alarmdt":"12-19-15 11:29:16 PM","activity":"Alarm on Main Door"},
        {"alarmdt":"12-19-15 11:29:19 PM","activity":"2 Seconds Until Viewed"},
        {"alarmdt":"12-19-15 11:29:24 PM","activity":"Application was successfully launched"},
        {"alarmdt":"12-19-15 11:29:24 PM","activity":"Details: xx.xx.xx.xx"},
        {"alarmdt":"12-19-15 11:33:12 PM","activity":"Contacted Acme Office at (123) 456-7890"},
        {"alarmdt":"12-19-15 11:33:50 PM","activity":"Contacted Manager who stated his floor cleaner caused the alarm with a broom. The broom is near the door when the alert was sent."},
        {"alarmdt":"12-19-15 11:33:51 PM","activity":"Verified (04m 24s 00ms)"},
        {"alarmdt":"12-19-15 11:33:53 PM","activity":"Alarm Closed"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: just updated with expected output - thanks VR

Comment: That's kinda where I'm stuck (logic-wise) - you don't really know you're processing a mult-line comment until you've gone to the next iteration and found out it has a 'qual3' value and it's part of the previous comment. By then, you're already 1 iteration "ahead" if that makes sense. That's where I'm hitting the wall.

Comment: Is it dumb to use this approach - whenever I hit a "Comment" entry with a NULL "QUAL3" field (means it's a new comment), that I perform a query to fetch all potential additional comment records that match that QUAL3 field? Would add some SQL calls, but the logic would be much easier for me... (my DB is very high performance if it matters - this is being used at most by 3 concurrent users at any given time)

Comment: Correct, fetching all records with 1 query currently - but am thinking of modifying to run whatever additional queries are needed depending on number of "Comment" entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you take inspiration from something like this:

```
<?php

define('EVTYPE', 0);
define('LOGDATE', 1);
define('QUAL', 2);
define('QUAL2', 3);
define('QUAL3', 4);
define('EVSTRING', 5);

$handle = fopen('./test.txt', 'r');
$comments = Array();

while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $arr = array_map('trim', explode('|', $line));
    if ($arr[EVTYPE] !== 'Comment') continue;

    if ($arr[QUAL3] === 'NULL') {
        array_push($comments, $arr);
    } else {
        $comments[count($comments)-1][EVSTRING] .= ' ' . $arr[EVSTRING];
    }
}

foreach ($comments as $arr){
    echo sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",
        $arr[EVTYPE], $arr[LOGDATE], $arr[QUAL],
        $arr[QUAL2], $arr[QUAL3], $arr[EVSTRING]
    );
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

Sample text file (which may as well be an array of your data)

```
Viewed|          05:29:19.000|    -1|      4|       2|       NULL
Comment|         05:29:24.083|    0|       0|       NULL|    Application was successfully launched
Comment|         05:29:24.437|    0|       0|       NULL|    Details: xx.xx.xx.xx
Action|          05:33:12.000|    1|       1|       982|     Acme Anvils
Response Time|   05:33:12.000|    -1|      4|       2|       NULL
Comment|         05:33:50.000|    0|       0|       NULL|    Contacted Manager who stated
Comment|         05:33:50.000|    0|       0|       4062146| his floor cleamer caused the alarm with a broom. The broom is
Comment|         05:33:50.000|    0|       0|       4062146| near the door when the alert was sent.
Comment|         05:33:51.890|    0|       0|       NULL|    Verified (04m 24s 00ms)
Action|          05:33:53.000|    12|      0|       -1|      NULL
Resolution|      05:33:53.000|    -1|      1|       -1|      NULL
```

Run:

```
$ php test.php
Comment 05:29:24.083    0       0       NULL    Application was successfully launched
Comment 05:29:24.437    0       0       NULL    Details: xx.xx.xx.xx
Comment 05:33:50.000    0       0       NULL    Contacted Manager who stated his floor cleamer caused the alarm with a broom. The broom is near the door when the alert was sent.
Comment 05:33:51.890    0       0       NULL    Verified (04m 24s 00ms)
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment that we also need other items, not just Comments, replace

```
if ($arr[EVTYPE] !== 'Comment') continue;
```

with

```
if ($arr[EVTYPE] !== 'Comment') {
    array_push($comments, $arr);
    continue;
}
```

Result will be:

```
Viewed  05:29:19.000    -1      4       2       NULL
Comment 05:29:24.083    0       0       NULL    Application was successfully launched
Comment 05:29:24.437    0       0       NULL    Details: xx.xx.xx.xx
Action  05:33:12.000    1       1       982     Acme Anvils
Response Time   05:33:12.000    -1      4       2       NULL
Comment 05:33:50.000    0       0       NULL    Contacted Manager who stated his floor cleamer caused the alarm with a broom. The broom is near the door when the alert was sent.
Comment 05:33:51.890    0       0       NULL    Verified (04m 24s 00ms)
Action  05:33:53.000    12      0       -1      NULL
Resolution      05:33:53.000    -1      1       -1      NULL
```

EDIT 2:

I've used MySQL database to demonstrate how this can be adapted to your case. Example of the database is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/549cf/1

Data looks like this:

```
|        evtype |                   logdate | qual | qual2 |   qual3 |                                                      evstring |
|---------------|---------------------------|------|-------|---------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|        Viewed | January, 01 2015 05:29:19 |   -1 |     4 |       2 |                                                        (null) |
|       Comment | January, 01 2015 05:29:24 |    0 |     0 |  (null) |                         Application was successfully launched |
|       Comment | January, 01 2015 05:29:24 |    0 |     0 |  (null) |                                          Details: xx.xx.xx.xx |
|        Action | January, 01 2015 05:33:12 |    1 |     1 |     982 |                                                   Acme Anvils |
| Response Time | January, 01 2015 05:33:12 |   -1 |     4 |       2 |                                                        (null) |
|       Comment | January, 01 2015 05:33:50 |    0 |     0 |  (null) |                                  Contacted Manager who stated |
|       Comment | January, 01 2015 05:33:50 |    0 |     0 | 4062146 | his floor cleamer caused the alarm with a broom. The broom is |
|       Comment | January, 01 2015 05:33:50 |    0 |     0 | 4062146 |                        near the door when the alert was sent. |
|       Comment | January, 01 2015 05:33:52 |    0 |     0 |  (null) |                                       Verified (04m 24s 00ms) |
|        Action | January, 01 2015 05:33:53 |   12 |     0 |      -1 |                                                        (null) |
|    Resolution | January, 01 2015 05:33:53 |   -1 |     1 |      -1 |                                                        (null) |
```

PHP script:

```
<?php

define('EVTYPE', 0);
define('LOGDATE', 1);
define('QUAL', 2);
define('QUAL2', 3);
define('QUAL3', 4);
define('EVSTRING', 5);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz');
$result = $mysqli->query('select * from logging');
$comments = Array();

while(($arr = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) !== NULL) {
    if ($arr[EVTYPE] !== 'Comment') {
        array_push($comments, $arr);
        continue;
    }

    if (is_null($arr[QUAL3])) {
        array_push($comments, $arr);
    } else {
        $comments[count($comments)-1][EVSTRING] .= ' ' . $arr[EVSTRING];
    }
}

foreach ($comments as $arr){
    echo sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",
        $arr[EVTYPE], $arr[LOGDATE], $arr[QUAL],
        $arr[QUAL2], $arr[QUAL3], $arr[EVSTRING]
    );
}
?>
```

Results:

```
Viewed  2015-01-01 05:29:19     -1      4       2
Comment 2015-01-01 05:29:24     0       0               Application was successfully launched
Comment 2015-01-01 05:29:24     0       0               Details: xx.xx.xx.xx
Action  2015-01-01 05:33:12     1       1       982     Acme Anvils
Response Time   2015-01-01 05:33:12     -1      4       2
Comment 2015-01-01 05:33:50     0       0               Contacted Manager who stated his floor cleamer caused the alarm with a broom. The broom is near the door when the alert was sent.
Comment 2015-01-01 05:33:52     0       0               Verified (04m 24s 00ms)
Action  2015-01-01 05:33:53     12      0       -1
Resolution      2015-01-01 05:33:53     -1      1       -1
```

Comment: That' s pretty neat zed - I'll read through it, but would note that the output should have the other record types as well (in proper order based on the LOGDATE).

Comment: Ah, good point about other records. I have edited the answer at the bottom and included the change you may need to make to get all records in decent order

Comment: Not realllll sure I know how to "adapt" that from a file input source... the field names being constants is throwing me I think.

Comment: Oh okay, let me see if I can create an example with mysqli_fetch_array for you. Perhaps that might make things easier.

Comment: I've added code using PHP/MySQL. Hopefully you can adapt this to your scenario

Comment: Struggling for some reason.. I'm using SQL Server, but updated accordingly. I'm not understanding why you made the field names constants? And that's confusing me when you're using those constants in the index references of the array. For my loop, i'm using "while( $arr = odbc_fetch_array($result) )"

Comment: In my example I am asking MySQL to give me 0...n fields numerically rather than by their field name. The `define` statements are to create something similar to enumerated constants. I believe you are using field names supplied by SQL Server. So, instead of using `$arr[EVTYPE]` (notice no quotation around EVTYPE), use `$arr['EVTYPE']` (notice quotes around EVTYPE). Quote your other fieldnames also.

Comment: Cool! That gets me off and running - looks like you built an array that resembles the SQL output with the comment parts combined. Now I can loop through THAT array and do my formatting and output conditions. You're the man!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98525/discussion-between-source-matters-and-zedfoxus).